# GeoServer 2.14.0 / Cascading / WMTS : Can't parse crs IGNF:LAMB93:Authority "IGNF" is unknown

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wmts

I want to cascade a WMTS service (IGN France) with my GeoServer 2.14.0 :
https://wxs.ign.fr/pratique/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

1) The URL works just fine in QGIS (2.14.22, "Essen") and I can see the map

2) When I add it as a store in GeoServer, there's a problem with the projection "IGNF:LAMB93". GeoServer doesn't know it:

`org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception 'Can't parse crs IGNF:LAMB93:Authority "IGNF" is unknown or doesn't match the supplied hints. Maybe it is defined in an unreachable JAR file?' occurred during validation org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMTSStoreNewPage$WMTSCapabilitiesURLValidator on component 14:form:capabilitiesURL:border:border_body:paramValue`

3) I found this to add in ./geoserver/data/user_projections/epsg.properties

http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7527/

```
PROJCS["Lambert 93",
GEOGCS["Reseau geodesique francais 1993",
    DATUM["Reseau geodesique francais 1993",
        SPHEROID["IAG GRS 1980",6378137.0000,298.2572221010000,
            AUTHORITY["IGNF","ELG037"]],
        TOWGS84[0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["IGNF","REG024"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.000000000,
        AUTHORITY["IGNF","LGO01"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994330],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["IGNF","RGF93G"]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP",
    AUTHORITY["IGNF","PRC0140"]],
PARAMETER["semi_major",6378137.0000],
PARAMETER["semi_minor",6356752.3141],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",46.500000000],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",3.000000000],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",44.000000000],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",49.000000000],
PARAMETER["false_easting",700000.000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",6600000.000],
UNIT["metre",1],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["IGNF","LAMB93"]]
```

4) after adding the one for GeoServer  (http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7527/geoserver/) and restarting GeoServer , the new projection is in the list of GeoServer  (under the name EPSG:7527) but it still doesn't recognize the IGNF:LAMB93 when adding the WMTS store...

I have no idea what to do now.
How come GeoServer says he doesn't know authority "IGNF:LAMB93" but can read it ? (last line of WKT)

Comment: Please raise a bug

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer has been built from the ground up 15+ years ago to support only the "EPSG" authority and a few others (e.g. CRS:84). Making it support user configurable authorities is going to be a large-ish task, funding welcomed, see:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer

As for cascading, I'm guessing there should be a much cheaper workaround to get it going, but it would still require coding.